# How to check for a specific string between multiple strings with regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have this following string:

```
(...)
<TEST NAME="KBC1" ID="0034" PRA="RUNNING DOG" />
<TEST NAME="KBC2" ID="0264" PRB="STANDING CAT" />
<TEST NAME="KBC1" ID="4632" TEM="HAPPY DOG" />
<TEST NAME="KBC6" ID="4492" LST="FLYING BIRD" />
(...)
```

The program should check for the word DOG, only if *NAME="KBC1"* and TEM="(..)" contains the word HAPPY. That would be true for the third line. It works partly with following pattern:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("<TEST NAME="KBC1"(.*)\/>");
```

How can I include the case for checking if TEM="(...)" contains the word "DOG" without creating two patterns?

Comment: Maybe `<TEST NAME="KBC1"(.*?)TEM=".*?DOG.*?"`? I don't really understand the question.

Comment: ``"<TEST NAME="KBC1"([^>]*\\bDOG\\b[^>]*)/>"``

Comment: @RoyalBg Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know, that you could chain ".*?" one after another...

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this basic code  will solve you query.

```
String input="<TEST NAME=\"KBC1\" ID=\"4632\" TEM=\"HAPPY DOG\" />";
        
        String regex = "^(?=.*\\bTEST NAME\\b)(?=.*\\bKBC1\\b)(?=.*\\bTEM\\b)(?=.*\\bHAPPY\\b)(?=.*\\bDOG\\b).*$";
        
        if(Pattern.matches(regex, input)) {
            System.out.println("match");
        }else {
            System.out.println("unmatch");
        }
```